# Basic "rank" question for $\binom{m}{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, manifolds

In my differential manifolds text, I've seen $\binom{m}{k}$ or a similar matrix form for rank of a vector space or topological space, and I haven't been able to get what this means straight in my head.  Any help?

Here is an example for context. Let $\dim V=n$ and consider direct sum $\oplus \Lambda^p V$ as one linear space. Then $$\dim (\oplus_{p=0}^n \Lambda^p V)= \sum_{p=0}^n \binom{n}{p}= 2^n.$$  Therefore, if the matrix form of the rank is "pre"-numerical rank, how would I get $2^n$ from $\binom{n}{p}$?

Comment: Does this mean rank of m x k?

Comment: Or, maybe the rank has two degrees under matrix form such as the (m-r)(n-r) question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518202/what-is-the-codimension-of-matrices-of-rank-r-as-a-manifold.

Comment: A concise notation for $\binom{m}{k}$ is `\binom{m}{k}` or `{m\choose k}`. I've edited the question using the former one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that these terms are simply the binomial coefficients

$$
{n \choose p} \;\; =\;\; \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}.
$$

It can be shown that the dimension of the vector space of alternating $p$-forms $\Lambda^pV$ is in fact ${n\choose p}$ and the resulting sum is simply just an application of the binomial theorem:

$$
\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} \;\; =\;\; \sum_{p=0}^n {n \choose p} 1^p 1^{n-p} \;\; =\;\; (1+1)^n \;\; =\;\; 2^n.
$$

Comment: Awesome! Much appreciated!